# Can a standalone gradle plugin export a custom task type?

Tags: gradle, gradle-task, gradle-custom-plugin

I have a [standalone Gradle plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html#sec:custom_plugins_standalone_project) that includes a custom task type:

**gradle-conventions/build.gradle**

```groovy
plugins {
  id 'groovy-gradle-plugin'
  id 'maven-publish'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '1.0'

publishing {
  repositories {
    maven {
      url = uri('/path/to/repo')
    }
  }
}
```

**gradle-conventions/src/main/groovy/com.example.my-conventions.gradle**

```groovy
abstract class CustomTask extends DefaultTask {
    @TaskAction
    def hello() {
        println "hello"
    }
}
```

I can consume the plugin from another project, but how can I register a `CustomTask`?  Something like this:

**project/build.gradle**

```groovy
plugins {                                                                       
  id 'com.example.my-conventions' version '1.0'
}

// how do I reference CustomTask here?
tasks.register('myCustomTask', com.example.CustomTask) {
  // ...
}
```

Is it possible to export a custom task from a custom plugin?  Or must I  [consume custom tasks using the `buildscript` mechanism](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_tasks.html#sec:using_your_task_class_in_another_project)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having inspected `gradle-conventions-1.0.jar`, it seems that the custom task class belongs to the default package, so I can register the task as follows:

**project/build.gradle**

```groovy
plugins {                                                                       
  id 'com.example.my-conventions' version '1.0'
}

tasks.register('myCustomTask', CustomTask) {
  // ...
}
```

But this only works `com.example.my-conventions.gradle` contains groovy code besides the class itself, otherwise I get the error:

```
An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'com.example.my-conventions', version: '1.0']
> Failed to apply plugin 'com.example.my-conventions'.
   > java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: precompiled_ComExampleMyConventions
```

This approach avoids relying on the [`buildscript` mechanism](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html#sec:build_script_external_dependencies) (which is not recommended in the Gradle documentation).